# How to disable internet access for particular application in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to disable internet for particular application, Please suggest me how to achieve because many application given this type of feature

Comment: Are you writing the application, or do you want this for some app that you've downloaded/came pre=installed?  In the second case, you'd need to root the phone and use an app that allows you to set permissions per app.  Google briefly released one and then pulled it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you are asking to control this in an app you are writing yourself or in a 3rd party app on your device

For 3rd party apps: Android 4.3 had a permission manager that allowed adjusting permissions individually for installed apps. This feature was pulled (Google said it was released by mistake) from Android 4.4 and it no longer available. A similar feature might be available on vendor-specific/un-official ROMs.

For apps you write yourself: You need to add proper permissions (`android:name="android.permission.INTERNET`) to access network. Without it the app will not be able to make any network traffic.